# How to run PHP application out of localhost?

Tags: php, localhost, local

I got this task form school, to make a PHP web application. But I don't really understand what this requirement might mean

> It should be possible to run this application outside the domain root 
>       e.g. sample URL: http://localhost/task/.

I searched a little bit on the internet but was not able to find anything that I could understand ?

I have wamp, and the folder where is my sites is `wamp/www/task`

Comment: You are on correct way !! Where you are stuck ?

Comment: I am not sure if I am stuck, I just don't even understand what the requirement meant? :)

Answer (score 1):

When they say "outside of domain root" it means that you should not be forced to go to

```
http://localhost/yourfile.php
```

but you could put it in a subdir, like

```
http://localhost/task/yourfile.php
```

What they want you to do is harder to guess, but it could mean that you need to be able to run it in any subdir, so take care of you imports to be able to handle that (e.g.: not hardcode the dir you're working in).

Answer (score 1):

Domain root seems to be at `localhost`, this just means it should be easy to rename your web application folder and make it still work at anywhere.

```
# http://localhost/task
$ cd wamp/www/

# http://localhost/task2 - should be accessible without you needing to change anything
$ mv task task2
```

From technical point of view, you should use relative path for all your links and images as well as external resources such as javascript / css files

Answer (score 1):

you can set vitual host for your web server & access your PHP Application likw www.oorja.local

in the wamp server, just add below code at end of your httpd.conf file, which allow you access your PHP application without localhost, Document root and Directory have your physical pathe of your application directory.

ServerName oorja.local
        DocumentRoot E:/LAMPSYSTEM/wamp/www/oorja/public

```
      <Directory E:/LAMPSYSTEM/wamp/www/oorja/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```